# How do I return a column based on date filter

Tags: dax

Sorry, new here (and to DAX in general!).

I am currently stuck trying to return a column of **values** based on a **date**. Take the following data example:

| Date | Value | Category | AvgValueForThisDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/02/2000 | 0.1 | A | ? |
| 05/02/2000 | 0.2 | B | ? |
| 06/02/2000 | 0.3 | C | ? |
| 07/03/2001 | 0.2 | C | ? |
| 08/03/2001 | 0.1 | A | ? |
| 09/04/2001 | 0.2 | B | ? |

---

So, I should be able to obtain for 05/02/2000, an array of:

| Value |
| --- |
| 0.1 |
| 0.2 |

Which I can then average and place into the column AvgValueForThisDate.

Thanks.

So far, I am unsure what DAX functions I could potentially use to return the array to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to break-out of the row-context to get the other rows' values.

Create a Measure with:

```
Avg Daily = 
  CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('YourTable'[Value]),
    ALLEXCEPT('YourTable', 'YourTable'[Date])
  )
```